# Cast video using Google chromecast feature

Tags: ios, video, chromecast

I have read the document here https://developers.google.com/cast/ for casting purpose.

Requirement of application is to develop application than allow user to cast video on TV.

1. My question is as a developer we need to take care of only sender side, right ?

If no than how to create receiver side coding ?

2. Is there any way to test it without using TV and chromecast device?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It might be good if you read some more on cast on the same site under "[Guides](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers)", that tells you all the components needed.

- You don't have to write a receiver if you are happy with the Default/Styled receiver that is provided by Google. Read the link above to see how it can be done.
- For testing, you need a real cast device like a Chromecast or Android TV.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have chromecast device but dont have TV. Can Mac act as a TV?

Comment: If you have a monitor that takes HDMI, it *may* work.