# Android SDK level 30 Cast Video to Chromecast using MediaRouter API

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, mediarouter

I want to cast my android app's UI to Chromecast device (connected to HDMI monitor) using MediaRouter with the latest apis in Android Q. I am able to do : 1)screencast to Samsung TV using SmartView and writing a Presentation class. 2) My app detects the Chromecast devices but I am not sure how to cast video it. It doesn't show UI on chromecast like how it does on Samsung TV with SmartView. On my Chromecast, Netflix and YouTube play well.

I saw other discussions on SO : [Cast video using Google chromecast feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971029/cast-video-using-google-chromecast-feature) but it's old and classes seem deprecated or don't work with android api level 30.

I will appreciate if someone can tell how I can cast my app's video/screen to Chromecast like Netflix or YouTube do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

learnt that we can cast only urls from webserver.

sample : https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android

to play video from local device, we need to host this in a webserver and send those urls to webserver to chromecast